# Sending daily message via GCM server on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to perform following.

1. I have deployed Google App Engine Server on Google App Engine.
2. Created dailyMessage.html within Web-INF at WEB-INF/data/dailyMessage.html
3. Trying to send the content of dailyMessage.html as Payload message.

However i have to upload this data file on daily basis to send updated message everyday. Is there any other way to achieve this functionality? I tried to explore for BlobStore functionality. However i didn't get the way i can upload and replace the file and access it via HTTP URL. Any help to achieve above functionality would be appreciable.

Comment: you can't edit "local" files on GAE so blobstore is the only way to go. You'd create AND serve the file from the blobstore.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood - Can you please let me know any references if you have to upload file on blobstore using JAVA?

Comment: It's all in the docs. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're manually creating the daily message, if so create a POST handler that allows you to POST the daily message.

Otherwise, if it's automatically generated, use a cron job that generates the message and sends it.